# How to simply parse JSON string from a website to C#

Tags: c#, json

so I have a problem:

The code in JSON that you see there is a response that a webpage gives me. And the thing I want to do is really simple:
I just want to parse for example the "user_id", or "class".

I tried few things on stackoverflow that I found but no one works...

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "class": "user",
      "user_id": "81046537",
      "etp_guid": "76411082-73ab-5aaa-9242-0bb752cf97a4",
    },
  },
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Sorry i failed the code box

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can extract the user_id from the json. The most common way is to use **Newtonsoft.Json** package.

Assuming the json is stored as a string, you can call JObject.Parse().

```
var data = "{'data': {'user': {'class': 'user','user_id': '81046537','etp_guid': '76411082-73ab-5aaa-9242-0bb752cf97a4'} } }";
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(data);
var userId = jObject["data"]["user"]["user_id"];
Console.WriteLine($"User id {userId}");
```

If your json is stored as a n object, then call `JObject jObject = new JObject(data)`

A preferred way is to serialise your json using business object. Simply create classes to match the json structure. e.g:

```
public class Response
{
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
        
public class Data
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Class { get; set; } 
    public string User_id { get; set; }
    public string Etp_guid { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize your object. e.g:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(data); 
Console.WriteLine($"User id {response.Data.User.User_id}");
```

Comment: Yes it's a string, but the values changes at every refresh... the first exemple is good but i don't think it works if value changes every refreshs

Comment: If the json is refreshed, then you'll need to do additional calls to extract the data. If you need help, then upload the full code.